# natural ergonomic keyboard zoom visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard

So i have done a tone of digging and can not find a way to enable the zoom button on my Microsoft natural ergonomic keyboard 4000 for visual studio (at my previous job this feature just worked. no configuration need). I found this blog http://www.pchenry.com/Home/tabid/36/EntryId/77/Do-you-have-a-Microsoft-Keyboard-with-a-Zoom-Complex.aspx that suggest modifying the commands.xml file used by the keyboard. I gave this a shot but the problem is I don't know the UniqueName or AppName for Visual Studio. below is the list of different UniqueName/AppName combos i have tried.

Also one last detail. I am not using IntelliType Pro like the article. Instead I am using Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center. The only difference I can find with this is the GUI. the underlying commands.xml and itype.exe look to be unchanged.

```
<Application UniqueName="MicrosoftVisualStudio" AppName="Microsoft Visual Studio 2013">
  <C319 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ." />
  <C320 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ," />
</Application>
<Application UniqueName="MicrosoftVisualStudio" AppName="Visual Studio">
  <C319 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ." />
  <C320 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ," />
</Application>
<Application UniqueName="MicrosoftVisualStudio" AppName="Microsoft Visual Studio">
  <C319 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ." />
  <C320 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ," />
</Application>
<Application UniqueName="MicrosoftVisualStudio" AppName="devenv">
  <C319 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ." />
  <C320 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ," />
</Application>
<Application UniqueName="devenv" AppName="Microsoft Visual Studio 2013">
  <C319 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ." />
  <C320 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ," />
</Application>
<Application UniqueName="devenv" AppName="Microsoft Visual Studio">
  <C319 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ." />
  <C320 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ," />
</Application>
<Application UniqueName="devenv" AppName="devenv">
  <C319 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ." />
  <C320 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ," />
</Application>
<Application UniqueName="devenv" AppName="Visual Studio">
  <C319 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ." />
  <C320 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ," />
</Application>
<Application UniqueName="VisualStudio" AppName="Visual Studio">
  <C319 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ." />
  <C320 Type="5" KeySeq="ctrl shift ," />
</Application>
```

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio in Admin mode? I'm only unable to scroll with elevated permissions, by depending on the StandardSupport catch-all

Comment: @Nyk that's it, elevated permissions and zooming is not possible. That's making me sad.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has this problem I had to run itype.exe as an administrator to give itype the ability to override other administrator programs. Otherwise itype could override the scrollability of non admin programs no problem.

https://pastebin.com/hCYf552k
          `<C319 Type="6" Activator="ScrollUp" />
      <C320 Type="6" Activator="ScrollDown" />`

Here is my commands.xml that allows scrolling on a MS ergo 4000